# Checkmarx error: Deserialization of untrusted data

Tags: java, jms, deserialization, checkmarx, validationmessage

I am getting deserialization of untrusted data during checkmarx scan (which find security related vulnarabilities in code) in the onMessage() method which is taking JMS message:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    log.debug("Code Run Started - In Queue");
    if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
        ObjectMessage objMes = (ObjectMessage) message;
        try {
            ChangeOperationType changeOperation = null;
            changeOperation = (ChangeOperationType) objMes.getObject();
        } catch (JMSException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            log.error("Message Type is incorrect (Not ChangeOperationType). ", e1);
        }
        try {
            callBackEndpoint = message.getStringProperty(CRMCommonProcessing.CALLBACK_ENDPOINT_URI_PROPERTY);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            log.error("CALLBACK ENDPOINT VALUE ERROR. ", e);
        }
        change(changeOperation);
    } else {
        log.error("WRONG MESSAGE TYPE GIVEN");
    }
    log.debug("Code Run Complete - In Queue");
}
```

Any fix or resolution for the issue?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who encounter this same issue in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`ObjectMessage` objects, which you are using in your `onMessage()` method, depend on Java serialization to marshal and unmarshal their object payload. This process is generally considered unsafe, because a malicious payload can exploit the host system. [Lots of CVEs](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=objectmessage) have been created for this. For this reason, most JMS providers force users to explicitly whitelist packages that can be exchanged using `ObjectMessage` messages. For example, here's the related [documentation for ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html#controlling-jms-objectmessage-deserialization).

There is no magic code fix for this issue that will eliminate the warning from checkmarx aside from removing the use of `ObjectMessage` from your code altogether (which is what I would actually recommend). If possible, define a data representation for the payload (JSON, protobuf, XML) and use a `javax.jms.TextMessage` or `javax.jms.BytesMessage` to carry it.

There are a number of other issues with use JMS `ObjectMessage` not related to security that you should [read about](http://jmesnil.net/weblog/2012/07/27/on-jms-objectmessage-and-its-pitfalls/) as well.

Comment: So in that case, what should we use instead of ObjectMessage in our code? Any suggestions?